# Nested Project For Testing Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rubygems

When creating a gem for a specific application framework, I nest a project within the gem in a test directory. For example, with a Rails specific gem I'd setup a directory structure like:

```
Rakefile
Gemfile
attached.gemspec
lib/attached.rb
lib/...
test/Gemfile
test/app/...
test/...
```

To test, I setup the nested project Gemfile using `gem 'attached', path: '...'` and run `rake test` inside the test directory. Is it possible to add a task to my main Rakefile that will allow me to run the tests in my sub project without changing into the directory first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the gem `enginex` to help me setup my gems with an integrated rails application.

In the root `Rakefile` they write:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs << 'lib'
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.pattern = 'test/**/*_test.rb'
  t.verbose = false
end

task :default => :test
```

They do not use a nested `Gemfile`, instead they load the Rails project inside the `test_helper.rb` and rails is a development/test dependency of the gem.

To check out the gem:

```
gem install enginex
```

Or check the [source](https://github.com/josevalim/enginex). This gem is included in rails 3.1 as the new plugin generator.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (and I think the least bug prone), would be to have a task like:

```
task :test do
  system('cd test; bundle exec rake test')
end
```

The other, more complicated way would be to include all "subtasks" in the root Rakefile add a prerequisite to each one of them, that will change the current directory, like so:

```
task :change_dir do
  puts 'changing dir'
  Dir.chdir('test')
end

namespace :sub do
  load 'test/Rakefile'
end
Rake::Task.tasks.select{|t| t.name.start_with?('sub:')}.each do |task|
  task.prerequisites.insert(0, 'change_dir')
end
```

I'm not sure how this will work with bundler though.

One last thing that I would recommend to you is to take a look at a project structure that `bundle gem` command creates. I use it for all my gems now, and I believe that taking advantage of it would make your problem go away entirely:)

Comment: @psycho Thanks. I'm using the directory structure provided by `bundle gem` however it does not provide any testing structure.

Comment: so if you are using it, why do you need two gemfiles?

Comment: @psycho The second file is for the test project. The 'test' folder contains a full Rails project (including the Gemfile).